# AWS Console doesn't load on Raspberry Pi (Chromium and Firefox)

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, chromium

I've been trying to access the AWS console so I can have one of our Cloudwatch dashboards on a TV using a Raspberry Pi but the console doesn't load. It used to work a long time ago though. I tried using Chromium and Firefox, but both gave the same error. This is what I am getting:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running any blocking add-ons? Some of the errors suggest some scripts failed to load. Maybe also check the network tab

Comment: Not really... It's a fresh installation, I also tried on a different PI and got the same error.

Comment: What firefox version does the raspberry pi ship with?

Comment: It actually doesn't, I installed it using apt, so it's probably the latest one.

Comment: It might not be. Have a look

Comment: I had a look and yea, it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was... The OS was quite old and even though it said that the installed browser was the latest version, it was the latest only for that old OS, not the actual latest. I re-installed the latest RaspberryPI OS to the device and now the AWS Console is working fine.